# Search through an irregular multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array I wish to search through it in PHP.

```
rgInventory": {
    "2294085379": {
        "id": "2294085379",
        "classid": "520025252",
        "instanceid": "0",
        "amount": "1",
        "pos": 41
    },
    "2383675126": {
        "id": "2383675126",
        "classid": "310781918",
        "instanceid": "0",
        "amount": "1",
        "pos": 40
    }
    //and so on...
```

As you can see the 2nd dimensional array is a spontaneous number. I am wishing to search for the classid, I would have the classid provided but how would I search for it, as I would want to find the id from the class id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `$result = json_decode($json, true)`:

```
foreach($result['rgInventory'] as $array) {
    if($array['classid'] == $classid) {
        echo $array['id'];
    }
}
```

Or a slicker way maybe:

```
echo array_column($result['rgInventory'], 'id', 'classid')[$classid];
```

Or even:

```
echo array_search($classid, array_column($result['rgInventory'], 'classid', 'id'));
```